# My brand new Dell Vostro got very slow after two days of usage, what can I do to fix it?

Tags: 12.04

I bought a `dell vostro` laptop with pre innstall ubuntu 12.04. Which was working very well but after 2 days it got slower.

what should i do to make it fast as earlier?

Comment: What programs did you install?

Answer (score 0):

As a start, check with the application "System Monitor" to see if there is anything hogging your device's resources. and report back.